# How do I serve assembly embedded resources from MVC 3 and IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, embedded-resource

I'm developing an MVC 3 application with a "plugin" functionality.  The
plugins are C# dll's with all required resources (css, images and scripts) embedded.

I've used the "MvcRazorClassGenerator" Visual Studio extension to create precompiled views.

I retrieve the embedded resource using the following code:

```
public FileStreamResult EmbeddedResource(string pluginName, string resourceName)
{
  Assembly assembly = PluginCache.GetAssembly(pluginName);

  if (assembly != null)
  {
    string tempResourceName =
      assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
              .ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(resourceName));

    return new FileStreamResult(
                  assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(tempResourceName), 
                  GetMIMEType(tempResourceName));
  }  

  return null;
}
```

In the views I have following code to access resources:

```
@Url.Content("/Common/EmbeddedResource/PluginName/[AssemblyNamespace].Content.Images.blank.gif")
```

All is working fine while I am in the development environment, all resources are loaded and displayed correctly, but when deploying, the nightmare is started.

IIS 7.5 keeps searching for a static file called "/Common/EmbeddedResource/PluginName/[AssemblyNamespace].Content.Images.blank.gif" and not the embedded file, giving me the 404 error for all embedded resources.

I've tried installing a hot fix mentioned by a question on this site and changing config files but the resources are not loaded.

I'm trying to deploy to Windows 2008 Server R2 SP1 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be the use of

```
Url.Content("/Common/EmbeddedResource/PluginName/[AssemblyNamespace].Content.Images.blank.gif")
```

I have the same set up but since the content is served from an action I use

```
@Url.Action("EmbeddedResource", "EmbeddedResources", new { pluginName = "PluginName", resourceName = "MyProject.Scripts.MyScript.js" })
```

I then set up a route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EmbeddedResources",
    "EmbeddedResources/{pluginName}/{resourceName}",
    new { controller = "EmbeddedResources", action = "EmbeddedResource", pluginName = "DefaultPluginName", resourceName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Which results in script references like so

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/EmbeddedResources/PluginName/MyProject.Scripts.MyScript.js'></script>
```

If you are taking this approach, you may also want to minify the embedded files (for release builds). You can do this using the MSBuild task as detailed on [this blog post](http://blog.turlov.com/2009/11/automatically-compress-embedded.html).

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ResGenDependsOn>
      MinifyJavaScript;
      $(ResGenDependsOn)
    </ResGenDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="MinifyJavaScript" Condition=" '$(ConfigurationName)'=='Release' ">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(EmbeddedResource)" DestinationFolder="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.js'">
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="EmbeddedJavaScriptResource" />
    </Copy>
    <AjaxMin JSSourceFiles="@(EmbeddedJavaScriptResource)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js" CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".css" JSLocalRenaming="CrunchAll" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Remove="@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.js'" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(EmbeddedJavaScriptResource)" />
      <FileWrites Include="@(EmbeddedJavaScriptResource)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an MVC framework available in [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) to help with managing reusable embedded resources.  It is called [Portable Areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/).  I have used it before on an open source project called [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) and it works great.

Comment: yes, I will take a look at this framework, (probably for future use, because I have almost finished this project and my boss, would not be happy if I propose to re-engeneer all ;) ). But regarding my question it seems that IIS is not calling the action if there is a "dot" in the URL... I've done a workaround for this, but at this time is just.. "curiosity"